# Conflicting Sage vs Wolfram evaluation of a limit?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, sage, wolframalpha

> Why are the following computed limits different (1 by Sage, 0 by Wolfram), and which (if either) is correct?

EDIT: Revised per @Bill's suggestion to increase the numerical precision in Wolfram. (I don't know how to do the same in Sage.) The Wolfram plot *strongly suggests* that the limit is indeed $0$, and that the issue is entirely about numerical precision.

**Sage**: (you can cut/paste/execute this code [here](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/))

```
#in()=
f(x) = exp(-x^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)
F(x) = (1 + erf(x/sqrt(2)))/2
num1(a,w) = (a+w)*f(a+w) - a*f(a)
num2(a,w) = f(a+w) - f(a) 
den(a,w) = F(a+w) - F(a)
V(a,w) = 1 - num1(a,w)/den(a,w) - (num2(a,w)/den(a,w))^2
assume(w>0); print(limit(V(a,w), a=oo))
plot(V(a,1),a,0,8)

#out()=
1        #<--------- computed limit = 1
```

[image]

**Wolfram**: (you can execute this code [here](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/app/objects/0e2860d3-6c86-4d61-a9cf-e97fcf88c3b5#sidebar=compute))

```
#in()=
f[x_]:=Exp[-x^2/2]/Sqrt[2*Pi]
F[x_]:=(1 + Erf[x/Sqrt[2]])/2 
num1[a_,w_] := (a+w)*f[a+w] - a*f[a]
num2[a_,w_] := f[a+w] - f[a]  
den[a_,w_] := F[a+w] - F[a]
V[a_,w_] := 1 - num1[a,w]/den[a,w] - (num2[a,w]/den[a,w])^2 
Assuming[w>0, Limit[V[a,w], a -> Infinity]]
Plot[V[a, 10], {a, 0, 100}, WorkingPrecision -> 128] 

#out()=
0        (* <--------- computed limit = 0 *)
```

[image]

(This is supposed to compute the limit, as a -> oo, of the [variance of a standard normal distribution when truncated to the interval (a,a+w)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution#Moments).)

Comment: You're better off asking at ask.sagemath.org, which is where the Sage expertise is.

Comment: @Iguananaut - Thanks, I've taken your advice by [cross-posting there](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/43517/conflicting-sage-vs-wolfram-evaluation-of-a-limit/).

Comment: It looks like you have some extremely large and extremely small values and are seeing catastrophic cancellation. For the Mathematica plot try `Plot[V[a, 1], {a, 0, 8}, WorkingPrecision -> 128]` which gives you a better behaved plot.

Comment: @Bill - Thank's very much -- it seems clearly a numerical precision issue, and that 0 really is the limit! Now I don't know whether to delete the question?

Comment: My guess would be that the incorrect symbolic result given by Sage has nothing to do with the numerical instability. It might be a bug in Sage. I'd report it to them. I would not delete.

Comment: @Szabolcs that is correct, they are two separate issues.  The cross-posted question answers both of them to some extent (symbolic is likely a bug in Maxima).